# Proof that all concave sequences obey a given inequality

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, convex-analysis

> A sequence $(a_n)$ is called concave if for all $n > 1, a_n \ge \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}}2$ and convex if $(-a_n)$ is concave. Prove that for every positive concave sequence $(a_k)_{k=1}^n, (\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)^2 \ge \frac{n-1}2 \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2.$

I think the following result might be useful, but I'm not entirely sure whether it's true or how to prove it:

$$i\ge 1, a_1+\cdots + a_i \ge i(\frac{a_1 + a_i}2)\tag{1}$$

I tried using induction, and the base case holds easily, but I can't seem to show that $a_1+\cdots + a_{i+1} \ge i(\frac{a_1 + a_i}2) + a_{i+1}$ implies the result. I need to use the fact that all the terms are positive, but I'm not sure how.

The proof would follow if $(1)$ holds because then by a similar argument $a_{i+1}+\cdots + a_n \ge (n- i + 1)(\frac{a_i + a_n}2)$ and so for any i, $a_1 + \cdots + a_n \ge \frac{n-1}2 a_i,$ and multiplying both sides by $a_i$ and summing for all $i$ gives the result.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/819445/42969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concavity assumption means that $b_k:=a_k-a_{k-1}$ satisfy
$b_{k+1}-b_k=a_{k+1}-2a_k+a_{k-1} \le 0$ for all $k >1$, so the sequence $(b_k)$ is weakly decreasing.
We will verify that every concave sequence $(a_j)$ satisfies
$$\forall i\ge 1, \quad a_1+\cdots + a_i \ge i(\frac{a_1 + a_i}2)\tag{1}$$
by induction on $i$, in jumps of $2$. The base cases $i=1,2$ are clear, so assume $i>2$. The induction hypothesis applied to the sequence $a_2,\ldots,a_{i-1}$ gives
$$ \quad a_2+\cdots + a_{i-1} \ge (i-2)(\frac{a_2 + a_{i-1}}2) \,.\tag{2}$$
Observe that
$$a_2 + a_{i-1}-(a_1+a_i)=b_2-b_{i} \ge 0 \,,$$
so $(2)$ yields
$$ \quad a_2+\cdots + a_{i-1} \ge (i-2)(\frac{a_1 + a_{i}}2) \,.\tag{3}$$
By adding $a_1+a_i$ to both sides of $(3)$, we obtain $(1)$.